# can not run task scheduler to automate python code

Tags: python, csv, automation, stock, price

I am trying to get the stock data. My code output is a csv file that store stock data. I want to run the code automatically so that the csv file is updated every 5 mins. I have tried task scheduler (because I use windows) but it returned no output. Below is my code.

```
from vnstock import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
stock_list = ['DVM']
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
# today = date.today()
today = pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
for stock in stock_list:
  df =  stock_historical_data(symbol=stock, start_date="2021-05-12", end_date = today)
  # df["stock"] = stock
  df.insert(0, "Stock", stock, True)
  df1 = pd.concat([df1,df])
df1.to_csv('C:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/code selenium/test.csv', index=False)
```